# AWS Cognito Groups via Amplify (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I want to be able to use the groups on Cognito to enable/disable some functionality on an app I'm building - only editors can edit for example.

Basic Cognito functionality (sign up/in/out etc) works, but for the life of me, I can't find a way of accessing the signed-in user's groups.

The test user I'm using is a member of two groups. I have the accessToken and idToken, but nothing is showing here either.

```
_ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession() { result in
    do {
            let session = try result.get()


            // Get user sub or identity id
            if let identityProvider = session as? AuthCognitoIdentityProvider {

                let usersub = try identityProvider.getUserSub().get()
                let identityId = try identityProvider.getIdentityId().get()

                print("User sub - \(usersub) and identity id \(identityId)")
            }

            // Get aws credentials
            if let awsCredentialsProvider = session as? AuthAWSCredentialsProvider {
                let credentials = try awsCredentialsProvider.getAWSCredentials().get()

                print("Access key - \(credentials.accessKey) ")

            }

            // Get cognito user pool token
            if let cognitoTokenProvider = session as? AuthCognitoTokensProvider {
                print(try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get().accessToken)
                let tokens = try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get()
                print("Id token - \(tokens.idToken) ")
            }

        } catch {
            print("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
        }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Cognito groups associated to the signed in user by parsing the token claims, that you can retrieve from the id token.

Here is what you need after you get the idToken. First, get the Token Claims:

```
let tokenClaims = try AWSAuthService().getTokenClaims(tokenString: tokens.idToken).get()
```

To get the Cognito groups from the Token Claims:

```
if let groups = (tokenClaims["cognito:groups"] as? NSArray) as Array?{
    let cognitoGroups : Set<String> = []
    for group in groups {
        print("Cognito group: \(group)")
        if let groupString = group as? String {
            cognitoGroups.insert(groupString)
        }
    }
 }
```

Putting it all together:

```
_ = Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession() { result in
do {
        let session = try result.get()


        // Get user sub or identity id
        if let identityProvider = session as? AuthCognitoIdentityProvider {

            let usersub = try identityProvider.getUserSub().get()
            let identityId = try identityProvider.getIdentityId().get()

            print("User sub - \(usersub) and identity id \(identityId)")
        }

        // Get aws credentials
        if let awsCredentialsProvider = session as? AuthAWSCredentialsProvider {
            let credentials = try awsCredentialsProvider.getAWSCredentials().get()

            print("Access key - \(credentials.accessKey) ")

        }

        // Get cognito user pool token
        if let cognitoTokenProvider = session as? AuthCognitoTokensProvider {
            print(try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get().accessToken)
            let tokens = try cognitoTokenProvider.getCognitoTokens().get()
            print("Id token - \(tokens.idToken) ")

            let tokenClaims = try AWSAuthService().getTokenClaims(tokenString: tokens.idToken).get()
            print("Token Claims: \(tokenClaims)")
            
            if let groups = (tokenClaims["cognito:groups"] as? NSArray) as Array?{
                let cognitoGroups : Set<String> = []
                for group in groups {
                    print("Cognito group: \(group)")
                    if let groupString = group as? String {
                        cognitoGroups.insert(groupString)
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Fetch auth session failed with error - \(error)")
    }
}
```